# How common/natural is it to omit いい after 〜なくても?

Tags: omission

I've noticed that in some visual novels I've played (mainly the ones set in older periods) that some characters tend to omit the いい after 〜なくても

For example, a character's line after being apologised to:

> 謝らなくても

However, I don't think I've really come across anyone who has omitted it like that, and after asking a native friend about it, he mentioned that if I just said "謝らなくても" alone, it sounds incomplete and as if I was just muttering something under my breath. Is the omission something that's not done anymore or was it never popular outside fiction to begin with? Would it really sound unnatural if I didn't add the いい at the back?

Answer (score 2):

It would not sound unnatural if you have the right context and the right tone. It'd be like having `...` in english for something like: "You could have just...". If you ask an english speaker if that's natural, they would say no. But this happens all the time in conversation. That's the same thing.